# How can I use sqlite driver from another path?

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

I created a java app with netbeans. And, I use sqlite database this like.

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:mydatabase.db");
```

This is my application files in "dist" folder when I was build project with right click.

```
dist\myapp.jar
dist\mydatabase.db
dist\lib\sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar
```

Driver file "sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar (~5mb)" in lib folder. I don't want to transport this file everytime. I want to use this file in "C:\Sqlite\". How can I do that.

Thanks for helping.. (Sorry my English grammar)

Comment: set the `classpath` to `C:\Sqlite\`

Comment: Please explane more.

Answer (score 0):

set classpath as "your driver path"
Goto MyComputer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Enviornment Variables
-> New ->
Name it variable name- classpath
           value- your driver path.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, but I didn't. What should I write exactly in "Variable name" and "Variable value".

Comment: variable name will be classpath and value will be your sqlite driver full path upto .jar.

Comment: Sorry Mahesh I didn't again. Could you please give an example?